# Express js, why there are two responses from the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I have just started learning express.js and node.js. I am trying to create a simple server, here is the code.

```
    const http = require('http');

    const express = require('express');

    const app = express();
    app.use((req, res, next)=>{
      console.log('in the middleware');
      next();
    });
    app.use((req, res, next)=>{
      console.log('in another middleware');
      res.send('<h1> I will handle this</h1>');
    });
    const server = http.createServer(app);

    server.listen(3000);
```

And it is working but in the console i see twice:
in the middleware
in another middleware
in the middleware
in another middleware

Shouldn't I see just:
in the middleware
in another middleware ?

Comment: How are you testing it? If you're calling from a browser the request for the favicon might be triggering too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you send a request?
It's most likely two different requests, if you print the url through `req.url` you'll be able to see it.

If you send a request through a browser it's probably a GET request and a request to the favicon of the site.

Comment: I guess that is the problem. When i print url, this is what I got:
in the middleware
/
in another middleware
/
in the middleware
/favicon.ico
in another middleware
/favicon.ico

But how to handle it?

Comment: It's not really something to handle, it's the behaviour of the browser to get and show the favicon (the icon of the site), so it sends two separate requests. If you use another tool to send a request like `curl` or `Postman` you will see only one request in your console.